# passing an image source via jquery remote

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I am currently trying to pass an image path to another page via remote in jQuery validation but can't seem to make it work.

My code:

```
'DP':{
    remote:{
    url:"checkdp.php",
    type:"get",
    data:{dp:$("#ImagePreviewDP").prop("src")}
    }
},
```

Other things tried(passing it as a function):

```
remote:{
    url:"checkdp.php",
    type:"get",
    data:function(){
    return $("#ImagePreviewDP").prop("src");
    }
}
```

my remote page:

```
require("../../inc/connection.inc");

$dp=$_GET['dp'];
$check=$cxn->prepare("SELECT `ItemDP` FROM `Items` WHERE `ItemDP`=:dp")
$check->bindValue(":dp",$dp);
$check->execute();
$count=$check->rowCount();

if($count > 0)
{
    echo json_encode(false);
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(true);
}
```

The remote call does not trigger any errors when $count is not greater than 0.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: where it is not working?

Comment: @kumar the remote call does not trigger any errors when it is passed to the page, i've updated my question to include the relevant code.